# Django 2 URL <int: > notation isn't behaving as expected

Tags: regex, path, python-3.5, django-urls, django-2.0

I have been migrating a platform from django 1.11 to django 2 for the past week with no issues, up until today, when I tried to update my urls. I have these 3 lines of code:

```
1. url(r'^track/(?P<track_id>[0-9]+)/user/playlists', views.music),
2. path(r'track/<int:track_id>/user/playlists', views.music),
3. re_path(r'^track/(?P<track_id>[0-9]+)/user/playlists',views.music),
```

1. the original line that worked fine in django 1.11.
2. the new line that I created to replace Line 1. I removed the caret '^' and replaced the RegEx.
3. the line I am using right now because it is working fine.

My issue here is that my test fails when I use Line 2 but passes when I use Line 3.What could possible cause this behavior?

PS: The test that fails is just a test that passes 14 to the URL and checks the response. The response should be 200 but is 404 instead. In fact, I tried pdb inside the music method, but the test finished without stopping there, which means that it didn't even go in.

```
self.check_response('/track/%d/user/playlists/' % 14)
```

Answer (score 0):

You're still using a regular expression in 2 because of the 'r'.

Make it like this:

`path('track/<int:track_id>/user/playlists', views.music),`

More details can be found [here.](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.1/topics/http/urls/#example)